# Function parameter default value in begin block

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following code:

```
Function test {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ParameterSetName="p1", position=0)]
    [string]$sFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ParameterSetName="p2", position=0)]
    [int]$iFile,
    [string]$Secret = "s3cr3t"
)
BEGIN {
    "[BEGIN]Secret=${Secret}"
}
PROCESS {
    "[PROCESS]Secret=${Secret}"
}
}
```

If i execute:

```
"file.txt" | test
```

I get:

> [BEGIN]Secret=
>
> [PROCESS]Secret=s3cr3t

My question is, why secret is empty in the begin block?

I am trying to perform some initialization actions in the begin block based on Secret and this behavior is stopping me.

Note that when i run test without pipeline input, the secret is initialized at BEGIN bock as well. Finally my powershell version is 2.

Comment: strange.. on my system (Powershell 5.1) it works. I would recommend adding this line right above the `Param` block: `[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="p1")]`

Comment: I've tried adding that with no results. I've also checked that my powershell is version 2, which might be the problem.

Comment: That's correct, I reproduced the same running `powershell.exe -version 2`

Comment: The problem disappears if you remove either one of the `$sFile` or `$iFile` parameters. Note that PowerShell does not recognize a different parameter set just by piping in values of different types, so what you're trying to do here can't work as-is anyway (if it is your intent to recognize different sets based on the pipeline alone).

Comment: @Jeroen: I am not sure if this is what you are referring to, but: "string"|test and 123|test should select different parameter sets

Comment: I thought it didn't, but it was carelessly checking `$PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName` in `BEGIN`. What actually happens is that the parameter set will be determined in every iteration of `PROCESS` (`1, "x", 1` gives different values).